# linked lists insertion function send argument by references misunderstanding

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, queue

I was reading through a book about C/C++ and I study linked lists from it.

I implement a LL as:

```
struct Node {
    int information; // the information of one node. assumed is that this is an integer only
    struct Node * next; // pointer which stores the address of next node in the list. points to next node in the list.
}

typedef struct Node * List;
```

I create `Insert` function as:

```
void Insert(List & First, List p, int x) { // First is given by reference because after insertion the First node can be changed.
    // Dynamically allocate new memory for the node we want to insert
    struct Node * q  = new Node;
    
    // Populate the new node with its information (the integer it contains)
    q -> information = x;

    if (!p) { // case 1: insert at beginning
        q -> next = First;
        First = q;
    }
    else { // case 2: insert in the middle of the list or at the end of the list
        q -> next = p -> next;
        p -> next = q; 
    }
}
```

My question is:

Why do we send the `First` parameter as reference and the `p` parameter not as a reference?
I see that `First` changes ''as a whole'', and only a ''piece'' of `p` changes, so ''not as a whole''. Would this be the reason?

```
First = q;

p -> next = q;
```

I am not extremely familiar with pointers, but if we send an address of a variable from a calling function to a called function, that called function can ''manipulate the variable'' because it doesn't copy on its stack the value of the actual parameter into a new object, but works on the actual variable from the stack of the calling function.

Why do we need then to write that reference sign, and why don't we need to write that sign for `p` as well?

I use this function to create a Queue as:

```
First = Last = NULL;
std::cin >> n; // this many events (n) will populate the Queue

for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    std::cin >> x; // the information of this i-th node.

    if (First) { // the Queue is NOT EMPTY
        Insert(First, Last, x);
        Last = Last -> next;
    }
    else { // the Queue is EMPTY
        Insert(First, NULL, x);
        Last = First;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: C has no references. Please do not mix C and C++, they are different languages. I also wonder how a single book manages to be an introduction to both.

Comment: *I see that First changes ''as a whole'', and only a ''piece'' of p changes, so ''not as a whole''. Would this be the reason?* That's exactly the reason.

Comment: Please don't typedef pointers. All you achieve that way is hiding information about your actual types that could be useful otherwise and could help avoid confustion, just as in your current case...

Comment: `First` points to the head of your list. What, if you need to modify this head because of filling an empty list or prepending an element? Without a reference, this change would never get visible outside of the function.

Comment: Style guide: the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly
because they are [postfix operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3) in C.
They should not be written with spaces around them.
Writing `Last -> next` is not idiomatic C or C++ and indicates that the coder
is a tyro (newbie).  Use `Last->next`.

Comment: Thanks to all, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does cause some confusion is this typedef (at least for me it was a source of confusion at first):

```
typedef struct Node * List;
```

So the arguments here:

```
void Insert(List & First, List p, int x) {
```

are actually

```
void Insert(Node*& First, Node* p, int x) {
```

Parameters are passed by value in C++, unless you pass them by reference. Pointers are no exception. When you call

```
Insert(head,node,42);
```

Then `Insert` will modify `head`, it will not modify `node` as you can see in the code:

```
void Insert(Node*& First, Node* p, int x) { 
    struct Node * q  = new Node;
    q->information = x;
    if (!p) {
        q->next = First;
        First = q;              // (1)
    } else {
        q->next = p->next;
        p->next = q;            // (2)
    }
}
```

Line `(1)` does modify `head` when it is passed to the function. Line `(2)` only modifies what the pointer points to not the pointer itself. If there was something along the line of

```
 p = nullptr;
```

in the function, then this would only modify the function local `p`, it would not affect `node` passed to the function. Because the function does not need to modify its second parameter, it is not passed as reference.

Answer (score 3):

> Why do we send the First parameter as reference and the p parameter not as a reference?

Because `First` may change (in a way that needs to be communicated to the caller) and `p` may not - exactly as the comment says.

> I see that First changes ''as a whole'', and only a ''piece'' of p changes

No, `p` doesn't change at all. Changing `p` would look like

```
p = new_value_for_p;
```

or

```
++p;
```

or something, but there is no such code

> ... only a ''piece'' of p changes

No no no. The variable `p` is a pointer. It never changes. Changing a pointer means you make it point to something else (or to nothing, with `nullptr`).

The line

```
p->next = q;
```

doesn't change "a piece" of `p`. It changes the object *referred to* by `p`. That object doesn't have a name, but we might call it `*p`. Changing the contents of this object *does not affect `p` at all*. Conversely, changing a pointer to point somewhere else *does not affect the object it points to*.

> I am not extremely familiar with pointers

This is obvious. You need to learn to understand pointer indirection, or you will always have trouble when reading code that uses pointers. And when I say "trouble" I mean *have no idea what the code is doing*.

Try taking a step back and drawing some box-and-pointer diagrams ([pdf](https://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/cs/csse120/Resources/C/BoxAndPointerDiagrams/discussion.pdf)).